# Fetching data from endpoint, retrieving coordinates, then merging into an output

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

I'm in no way a skilled developer (or even a developer at that!) but I did want to take a go at writing a script that fetched one endpoint's data, extracted some data, sent if off to be geocoded, then saved both the original (with geocodes) and the geocoded data to file. On subsequent requests, it would look up the geocoded data on file to check if anything matched, and pull data from there, otherwise trigger the fetch request again.

I think it works - at least it's been working from what I can tell but I'd love a review (or improvement if that's your thing) :)

```js
#!/usr/bin/env node

'use strict';

//
// MARK: - modules
//
const fs = require('fs');
const fetch = require('node-fetch');


//
// MARK: create the variables / constants
//

// get the command line arguments
const args = (function(argv) {

    // remove `node` and `script` name
    argv = argv.slice(2);

    // returned object
    var args = {};
    var argName, argValue;

    // loop through each argument
    argv.forEach(function(arg, index) {

        // seperate argument, for a key/value return
        arg = arg.split('=');

        // retrieve the argument name
        argName = arg[0];

        // remove "--" or "-"
        if (argName.indexOf('-') === 0) {
            argName = argName.slice(
                argName.slice(0, 2).lastIndexOf('-') + 1
            );
        }

        // associate defined value or initialize it to "true" state
        argValue = (arg.length === 2) ?

            // check if argument is valid number
            parseFloat(arg[1]).toString() === arg[1]

        ?
        +arg[1]: arg[1]

        :
        true;

        // finally add the argument to the args set
        args[argName] = argValue;
    });

    return args;
})(process.argv);



// api key checks
const apiKey = function() {

    // api not declared
    if (!args.api) {
        return 1;
    }

    // declared but empty
    if (args.api === true) {
        return 2;
    }

    // all good
    if (args.api && args.api !== true) {
        return args.api;
    }

}(args);



//
// MARK: - check the files and directories we need
//
const req = (() => {

    // where we store things
    const directory = './docs';
    const datavic = `${ directory }/datavic.json`;
    const database = `./database.json`;

    // checks and creation
    if (!fs.existsSync(directory)) {
        fs.mkdirSync(directory);
    }

    // array of items
    return {
        dir: directory,
        api: datavic,
        db: database
    }
})();



//
// MARK: - the script initialiser
//
function init() {
    console.time();
    fetchExposures();
    console.timeEnd();
}



//
// MARK: - 1. fetch the data from datavic
//
function fetchExposures() {

    // api check
    if (apiKey === 1) {
        return console.error(
            '[x] Exiting: API argument not declared!'
        );
    }
    if (apiKey === 2) {
        return console.error(
            '[x] Exiting: API key not provided!'
        );
    }

    // url: Data Victoria API
    const url = new URL(
        'https://discover.data.vic.gov.au/api/3/action/datastore_search'
    );

    // url: parameters
    url.searchParams.append(
        'resource_id', 'afb52611-6061-4a2b-9110-74c920bede77'
    );

    url.searchParams.append(
        'limit', '10000'
    );

    // fetch the data
    fetch(url)
        .then(res => res.json())

    .then(async data => {

        // send off data to be checked against database
        const valid = await validateData(data);

        // send off data to be checked against database
        const database = await checkDatabase(valid);

        // fetch the coordinates
        const coordinates = await fetchCoordinates(database);

        // add the coordinates to api file
        const api = await addCoordinates(data, coordinates);

        // write items to file
        await writeFiles(api, coordinates);
    })

    .catch(err => {
        console.error(`[x] Error: ${ err }`);
    });
}



//
// MARK: - 2. remove the bad characters
//
function validateData(input) {

    const sanitised = JSON.stringify(input, null, 2)
        .replace(/\\t/g, '')
        .replace(/\\r/g, '')
        .replace(/\\n/g, '')
        .replace(/\\v/g, '')
        .replace(/\\h/g, '');

    return JSON.parse(sanitised);
}



//
// MARK: - 3. check if any of the results are in the database
//
function checkDatabase(input) {

    // 3a. exlude any that have null address or postcode
    const inputNoNull = input.result.records.filter(item => {
        if (!(item.Site_streetaddress === null ||
                item.Site_postcode === null)) {
            return item
        }
    })

    // -- select only certain fields
    .map(item => ({
        Suburb: item.Suburb,
        Site_streetaddress: item.Site_streetaddress,
        Site_state: item.Site_state,
        Site_postcode: item.Site_postcode
    }))

    // -- sort by ID
    .sort((a, b) => {
        return a._id - b._id;
    });

    // -- get the unique data
    const data = [...new Set(
        inputNoNull.map(item1 =>
            item1.Suburb +
            item1.Site_streetaddress +
            item1.Site_state +
            item1.Site_postcode
        )
    )].map(
        item1 => inputNoNull.find(
            item2 =>
            item2.Suburb +
            item2.Site_streetaddress +
            item2.Site_state +
            item2.Site_postcode ==
            item1
        )
    );

    // -- read the database
    const db = fs.readFileSync(req.db);
    const database = db ? JSON.parse(db) : {};

    // append new items
    const mergeJSON = ((file1, file2) =>
        Object.values([...file1, ...file2]
            .reduce((left, right) => {
                const key = `${right.Suburb} ${right.Site_streetaddress} ${right.Site_state} ${right.Site_postcode}`;
                left[key] = left[key] || right;

                return left;
            }, {})
        )
    );

    // return it
    return mergeJSON(database, data);
}



//
// MARK: - 4. loop all items in database, fetch the coordinates
//
async function fetchCoordinates(input) {

    let geocodedSites = [];

    // loop over the locations
    for (let x = 0; x < input.length; x++) {
        try {
            const result = await getGeocode(input[x]);
            geocodedSites.push(result);
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(`[x] Error: ${ err }`);
        }
    }

    // return it
    return geocodedSites;
}



//
// MARK: - 5. re-check the results are in the database
//
function addCoordinates(data, coordinates) {

    const dataapi = data.result.records;

    let arr = [];

    // loop over the locations
    for (let x = 0; x < dataapi.length; x++) {
        coordinates.filter(item2 => {

            if (dataapi[x].Suburb === item2.Suburb &&
                dataapi[x].Site_streetaddress === item2.Site_streetaddress &&
                dataapi[x].Site_state === item2.Site_state &&
                dataapi[x].Site_postcode === item2.Site_postcode
            ) {
                // -- append the coordinates to the items
                const fulldata = {
                    ...dataapi[x],
                    latitude: item2.latitude,
                    longitude: item2.longitude
                }
                arr.push(fulldata);
            }
        });
    }

    // return it
    return arr;
}



//
// MARK: - 6. write files to system
//
function writeFiles(file1, file2) {

    // stringify the inputs
    const stringFile1 = JSON.stringify(file1, undefined, 2);
    const stringFile2 = JSON.stringify(file2, undefined, 2);

    // write them to disk
    fs.writeFileSync(req.api, stringFile1);
    fs.writeFileSync(req.db, stringFile2);
}



//
// MARK: - function: get the coordinates
//
async function getGeocode(site) {

    // build the address
    const query = `${site.Site_streetaddress} ${site.Suburb } ${site.Site_postcode } ${site.Site_state} Australia`;


    // 1. skip any with existing coordinates
    if (site.latitude && site.longitude || site.skip) {
        console.error(`[✔] Skipping: ${ query }`);
        return Promise.resolve(site);
    }

    // 2. fetch only missing items
    console.log(`[⦿] Geocoding: ${ query }`);

    // url: Data Victoria API
    const url = new URL(
        'http://api.positionstack.com/v1/forward'
    );

    // url: parameters
    url.searchParams.append(
        'access_key', apiKey
    );

    url.searchParams.append(
        'region', 'Victoria'
    );

    url.searchParams.append(
        'country', 'AU'
    );

    url.searchParams.append(
        'limit', '1'
    );

    // build the search query
    url.searchParams.append(
        'query', query
    )

    // fetch the data
    return fetch(url)
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(data => {

            const latitude = data.data[0].latitude;
            const longitude = data.data[0].longitude;
            const label = data.data[0].label;
            const confidence = data.data[0].confidence;

            return {
                ...site,
                confidence,
                latitude,
                longitude,
                label
            }
        })

    .catch(err => {
        console.log(`    [x] Failed: ${ query }`);
        return {...site,
            skip: true
        }
    });
}

//
// MARK: - success: if we got to here
//
init();
```